# How to create a global string method

Tags: ruby, methods

I want to create a global `String` method used as: `"string".convert_to_date` that I can use it in the same way as `"abc".length` or `"abc".upcase`.

How can I define `convert_to_date` method?

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to patching you can also define patches via refinements. This will make the patch only available in a certain scope. This isn't necessarily an issue with `String.convert_to_date`, but in a large scale project it's often recommended to avoid outright monkeypatching, to avoid conflicts with gems' code.

A refinement is defined and used like so:

```
module StringRefinement
  refine String do
    def convert_to_date
      self + " world"
    end
  end
end

class SomeClass
  using StringRefinement
  "hello".convert_to_date # => "hello world"
end

"hello".convert_to_date # => NoMethodError
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and deep explanation, this helps me understand a lot. But I need `convert_to_date` method can use in all contexts like: model, controller and views. And seems like refinement class method cannot use in views. I have found a solution, and I post it below

Comment: This is a proper way to go.

Comment: I agree, didn't know about refinements, thanks @max pleaner

Answer (score 6):

you can open up any class in ruby to add methods to it, for your case you can do

```
class String
  def convert_to_date
    # do something with the string, self will contain the value of the string 
  end
end
```

This will make that method available to any string object so make sure you know what you are doing and there are no side effects.

This is called monkey patching, I'm not sure if this is the best way for your use case without more context

If you're just trying to convert string date to date or time object, there already are methods like `Time.parse` or `DateTime.parse`

Comment: Thank you. It works. My string contains many characters, I have to use `gsub` to exclude them so I cannot use the built-in method alone. I updated my solution in the answer below

Comment: @PeterNguyen glad to be of help

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @Subash and @max pleaner, your answers helped me found a solution. And here is my solution:

in config/initializers/StringRefinementDate.rb:

```
module StringRefinementDate
  def convert_to_date
    self + " world"
  end
end
String.include StringRefinementDate
```

In `models`, `controllers`, and `views` just use:

```
"hello".convert_to_date # => "hello world"
```

Comment: This is absolutely the same as what @Subash suggested. Downvoted.

Comment: Sure you can. Once again: there is **no difference** between these two solutions, save for yours produces an invalid half-functional, includable to only classes defining `+(String)` instance method module.